# Intellij Device not Specified on UI editor android

Tags: android, intellij-idea

I just updated to the lastest version of Intellij Community, but when I try to edit a xml file i cannot preview it, get a Render Error - Device not Specified, how can I get the default configurations back?

Comment: What do you mean by the latest version? 11.1.4, 11.1.5 EAP, 12 EAP?

Comment: the version I'm talking is 12EAP

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/13422872/104891

Comment: i tried that solution but it doesnt seem to work on windows

Comment: the answer on the other thread solved it,replace devices.xml with a version from previous adt.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In order to have the device configuration in Intellij you'll need to modify the **`device.xml`** file from `USER_HOME/.android folder` to the **`device.xml`** from the `SDK_FOLDER/tools/lib/device.xml` and after that try to reopen the layout file file again in Intellij you'll get all the device configuration.

**BUT,** this will not work if you have the **latest version of Android SDK tools,**

IF you have the latest SDK then try to replace USER_HOME/.android/device.xml with below content. and try to reopen layout file in Intellij again.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<d:layout-devices
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/layout-devices/1">

    <d:device name="2.7in QVGA">
        <d:default>
            <d:screen-size>small</d:screen-size>
            <d:screen-ratio>notlong</d:screen-ratio>
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
            <d:pixel-density>ldpi</d:pixel-density>
            <d:touch-type>finger</d:touch-type>
            <d:keyboard-state>keyssoft</d:keyboard-state>
            <d:text-input-method>nokeys</d:text-input-method>
            <d:nav-state>navexposed</d:nav-state>
            <d:nav-method>nonav</d:nav-method>
            <d:screen-dimension>
                <d:size>240</d:size>
                <d:size>320</d:size>
            </d:screen-dimension>
            <d:xdpi>145</d:xdpi>
            <d:ydpi>145</d:ydpi>
        </d:default>

        <d:config name="Portrait">
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
        <d:config name="Landscape">
            <d:screen-orientation>land</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
    </d:device>

    <d:device name="2.7in QVGA slider">
        <d:default>
            <d:screen-size>small</d:screen-size>
            <d:screen-ratio>notlong</d:screen-ratio>
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
            <d:pixel-density>ldpi</d:pixel-density>
            <d:touch-type>finger</d:touch-type>
            <d:text-input-method>qwerty</d:text-input-method>
            <d:nav-state>navexposed</d:nav-state>
            <d:nav-method>nonav</d:nav-method>
            <d:screen-dimension>
                <d:size>240</d:size>
                <d:size>320</d:size>
            </d:screen-dimension>
            <d:xdpi>145</d:xdpi>
            <d:ydpi>145</d:ydpi>
        </d:default>

        <d:config name="Portrait">
            <d:keyboard-state>keyssoft</d:keyboard-state>
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
        <d:config name="Landscape, closed">
            <d:keyboard-state>keyssoft</d:keyboard-state>
            <d:screen-orientation>land</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
        <d:config name="Landscape, open">
            <d:keyboard-state>keysexposed</d:keyboard-state>
            <d:screen-orientation>land</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
    </d:device>

    <d:device name="3.2in HVGA slider (ADP1)">
        <d:default>
            <d:screen-size>normal</d:screen-size>
            <d:screen-ratio>notlong</d:screen-ratio>
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
            <d:pixel-density>mdpi</d:pixel-density>
            <d:touch-type>finger</d:touch-type>
            <d:text-input-method>qwerty</d:text-input-method>
            <d:nav-state>navexposed</d:nav-state>
            <d:nav-method>trackball</d:nav-method>
            <d:screen-dimension>
                <d:size>320</d:size>
                <d:size>480</d:size>
            </d:screen-dimension>
            <d:xdpi>180.6</d:xdpi>
            <d:ydpi>182</d:ydpi>
        </d:default>

        <d:config name="Portrait">
            <d:keyboard-state>keyssoft</d:keyboard-state>
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
        <d:config name="Landscape, closed">
            <d:keyboard-state>keyssoft</d:keyboard-state>
            <d:screen-orientation>land</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
        <d:config name="Landscape, open">
            <d:keyboard-state>keysexposed</d:keyboard-state>
            <d:screen-orientation>land</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
    </d:device>

    <d:device name="3.2in HVGA (ADP2)">
        <d:default>
            <d:screen-size>normal</d:screen-size>
            <d:screen-ratio>notlong</d:screen-ratio>
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
            <d:pixel-density>mdpi</d:pixel-density>
            <d:touch-type>finger</d:touch-type>
            <d:keyboard-state>keyssoft</d:keyboard-state>
            <d:text-input-method>nokeys</d:text-input-method>
            <d:nav-state>navexposed</d:nav-state>
            <d:nav-method>trackball</d:nav-method>
            <d:screen-dimension>
                <d:size>320</d:size>
                <d:size>480</d:size>
            </d:screen-dimension>
            <d:xdpi>180.6</d:xdpi>
            <d:ydpi>182</d:ydpi>
        </d:default>

        <d:config name="Portrait">
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
        <d:config name="Landscape">
            <d:screen-orientation>land</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
    </d:device>

    <d:device name="3.3in WQVGA">
        <d:default>
            <d:screen-size>normal</d:screen-size>
            <d:screen-ratio>long</d:screen-ratio>
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
            <d:pixel-density>ldpi</d:pixel-density>
            <d:touch-type>finger</d:touch-type>
            <d:keyboard-state>keyssoft</d:keyboard-state>
            <d:text-input-method>nokeys</d:text-input-method>
            <d:nav-state>navexposed</d:nav-state>
            <d:nav-method>nonav</d:nav-method>
            <d:screen-dimension>
                <d:size>240</d:size>
                <d:size>400</d:size>
            </d:screen-dimension>
            <d:xdpi>141</d:xdpi>
            <d:ydpi>141</d:ydpi>
        </d:default>

        <d:config name="Portrait">
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
        <d:config name="Landscape">
            <d:screen-orientation>land</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
    </d:device>
    <d:device name="3.4in FWQVGA">
        <d:default>
            <d:screen-size>normal</d:screen-size>
            <d:screen-ratio>long</d:screen-ratio>
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
            <d:pixel-density>ldpi</d:pixel-density>
            <d:touch-type>finger</d:touch-type>
            <d:keyboard-state>keyssoft</d:keyboard-state>
            <d:text-input-method>nokeys</d:text-input-method>
            <d:nav-state>navexposed</d:nav-state>
            <d:nav-method>nonav</d:nav-method>
            <d:screen-dimension>
                <d:size>240</d:size>
                <d:size>432</d:size>
            </d:screen-dimension>
            <d:xdpi>145</d:xdpi>
            <d:ydpi>145</d:ydpi>
        </d:default>

        <d:config name="Portrait">
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
        <d:config name="Landscape">
            <d:screen-orientation>land</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
    </d:device>

    <d:device name="3.7in WVGA (Nexus One)">
        <d:default>
            <d:screen-size>normal</d:screen-size>
            <d:screen-ratio>long</d:screen-ratio>
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
            <d:pixel-density>hdpi</d:pixel-density>
            <d:touch-type>finger</d:touch-type>
            <d:keyboard-state>keyssoft</d:keyboard-state>
            <d:text-input-method>nokeys</d:text-input-method>
            <d:nav-state>navexposed</d:nav-state>
            <d:nav-method>trackball</d:nav-method>
            <d:screen-dimension>
                <d:size>480</d:size>
                <d:size>800</d:size>
            </d:screen-dimension>
            <d:xdpi>254</d:xdpi>
            <d:ydpi>254</d:ydpi>
        </d:default>

        <d:config name="Portrait">
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
        <d:config name="Landscape">
            <d:screen-orientation>land</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
    </d:device>

    <d:device name="3.7in FWVGA slider">
        <d:default>
            <d:screen-size>normal</d:screen-size>
            <d:screen-ratio>long</d:screen-ratio>
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
            <d:pixel-density>hdpi</d:pixel-density>
            <d:touch-type>finger</d:touch-type>
            <d:text-input-method>qwerty</d:text-input-method>
            <d:nav-state>navhidden</d:nav-state>
            <d:nav-method>dpad</d:nav-method>
            <d:screen-dimension>
                <d:size>480</d:size>
                <d:size>854</d:size>
            </d:screen-dimension>
            <d:xdpi>265</d:xdpi>
            <d:ydpi>265</d:ydpi>
        </d:default>

        <d:config name="Portrait">
            <d:keyboard-state>keyssoft</d:keyboard-state>
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
        <d:config name="Landscape, closed">
            <d:keyboard-state>keyssoft</d:keyboard-state>
            <d:screen-orientation>land</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
        <d:config name="Landscape, open">
            <d:keyboard-state>keysexposed</d:keyboard-state>
            <d:screen-orientation>land</d:screen-orientation>
            <d:nav-state>navexposed</d:nav-state>
        </d:config>
    </d:device>

    <d:device name="4in WVGA (Nexus S)">
        <d:default>
            <d:screen-size>normal</d:screen-size>
            <d:screen-ratio>long</d:screen-ratio>
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
            <d:pixel-density>hdpi</d:pixel-density>
            <d:touch-type>finger</d:touch-type>
            <d:keyboard-state>keyssoft</d:keyboard-state>
            <d:text-input-method>nokeys</d:text-input-method>
            <d:nav-state>navexposed</d:nav-state>
            <d:nav-method>nonav</d:nav-method>
            <d:screen-dimension>
                <d:size>480</d:size>
                <d:size>800</d:size>
            </d:screen-dimension>
            <d:xdpi>235</d:xdpi>
            <d:ydpi>235</d:ydpi>
        </d:default>

        <d:config name="Portrait">
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
        <d:config name="Landscape">
            <d:screen-orientation>land</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
    </d:device>

    <d:device name="4.65in 720p (Galaxy Nexus)">
        <d:default>
            <d:screen-size>normal</d:screen-size>
            <d:screen-ratio>long</d:screen-ratio>
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
            <d:pixel-density>xhdpi</d:pixel-density>
            <d:touch-type>finger</d:touch-type>
            <d:keyboard-state>keyssoft</d:keyboard-state>
            <d:text-input-method>nokeys</d:text-input-method>
            <d:nav-state>navexposed</d:nav-state>
            <d:nav-method>nonav</d:nav-method>
            <d:screen-dimension>
                <d:size>720</d:size>
                <d:size>1280</d:size>
            </d:screen-dimension>
            <d:xdpi>316</d:xdpi>
            <d:ydpi>316</d:ydpi>
        </d:default>

        <d:config name="Portrait">
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
        <d:config name="Landscape">
            <d:screen-orientation>land</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
    </d:device>

    <d:device name="4.7in WXGA">
        <d:default>
            <d:screen-size>normal</d:screen-size>
            <d:screen-ratio>long</d:screen-ratio>
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
            <d:pixel-density>xhdpi</d:pixel-density>
            <d:touch-type>finger</d:touch-type>
            <d:keyboard-state>keyssoft</d:keyboard-state>
            <d:text-input-method>nokeys</d:text-input-method>
            <d:nav-state>navexposed</d:nav-state>
            <d:nav-method>nonav</d:nav-method>
            <d:screen-dimension>
                <d:size>1280</d:size>
                <d:size>720</d:size>
            </d:screen-dimension>
            <d:xdpi>320</d:xdpi>
            <d:ydpi>320</d:ydpi>
        </d:default>

        <d:config name="Portrait">
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
        <d:config name="Landscape">
            <d:screen-orientation>land</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
    </d:device>

    <d:device name="5.1in WVGA">
        <d:default>
            <d:screen-size>large</d:screen-size>
            <d:screen-ratio>long</d:screen-ratio>
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
            <d:pixel-density>mdpi</d:pixel-density>
            <d:touch-type>finger</d:touch-type>
            <d:keyboard-state>keyssoft</d:keyboard-state>
            <d:text-input-method>nokeys</d:text-input-method>
            <d:nav-state>navexposed</d:nav-state>
            <d:nav-method>nonav</d:nav-method>
            <d:screen-dimension>
                <d:size>480</d:size>
                <d:size>800</d:size>
            </d:screen-dimension>
            <d:xdpi>183</d:xdpi>
            <d:ydpi>183</d:ydpi>
        </d:default>

        <d:config name="Portrait">
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
        <d:config name="Landscape">
            <d:screen-orientation>land</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
    </d:device>

    <d:device name="5.4in FWVGA">
        <d:default>
            <d:screen-size>large</d:screen-size>
            <d:screen-ratio>long</d:screen-ratio>
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
            <d:pixel-density>mdpi</d:pixel-density>
            <d:touch-type>finger</d:touch-type>
            <d:keyboard-state>keyssoft</d:keyboard-state>
            <d:text-input-method>nokeys</d:text-input-method>
            <d:nav-state>navexposed</d:nav-state>
            <d:nav-method>nonav</d:nav-method>
            <d:screen-dimension>
                <d:size>480</d:size>
                <d:size>854</d:size>
            </d:screen-dimension>
            <d:xdpi>181</d:xdpi>
            <d:ydpi>181</d:ydpi>
        </d:default>

        <d:config name="Portrait">
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
        <d:config name="Landscape">
            <d:screen-orientation>land</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
    </d:device>

    <d:device name="7in WSVGA (Tablet)">
        <d:default>
            <d:screen-size>large</d:screen-size>
            <d:screen-ratio>long</d:screen-ratio>
            <d:screen-orientation>land</d:screen-orientation>
            <d:pixel-density>mdpi</d:pixel-density>
            <d:touch-type>finger</d:touch-type>
            <d:keyboard-state>keyssoft</d:keyboard-state>
            <d:text-input-method>nokeys</d:text-input-method>
            <d:nav-state>navexposed</d:nav-state>
            <d:nav-method>nonav</d:nav-method>
            <d:screen-dimension>
                <d:size>1024</d:size>
                <d:size>600</d:size>
            </d:screen-dimension>
            <d:xdpi>169</d:xdpi>
            <d:ydpi>169</d:ydpi>
        </d:default>

        <d:config name="Landscape">
            <d:screen-orientation>land</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
        <d:config name="Portrait">
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
    </d:device>


    <d:device name="10.1in WXGA (Tablet)">
        <d:default>
            <d:screen-size>xlarge</d:screen-size>
            <d:screen-ratio>long</d:screen-ratio>
            <d:screen-orientation>land</d:screen-orientation>
            <d:pixel-density>mdpi</d:pixel-density>
            <d:touch-type>finger</d:touch-type>
            <d:keyboard-state>keyssoft</d:keyboard-state>
            <d:text-input-method>nokeys</d:text-input-method>
            <d:nav-state>navexposed</d:nav-state>
            <d:nav-method>nonav</d:nav-method>
            <d:screen-dimension>
                <d:size>1280</d:size>
                <d:size>800</d:size>
            </d:screen-dimension>
            <d:xdpi>149</d:xdpi>
            <d:ydpi>149</d:ydpi>
        </d:default>

        <d:config name="Landscape">
            <d:screen-orientation>land</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
        <d:config name="Portrait">
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
    </d:device>
</d:layout-devices>
```

Comment: no worries just create one device.xml and paste the above xml content and you'll good to go

Comment: That got rid of the error in the dropdowns in the preview, but  now there's a new issue, and the preview still isn't working. Now it says "This version of the rendering library is more recent than your version of IntelliJ IDEA. Please update IntelliJ IDEA", but I am running the latest version.

Comment: intellij does not have a render version for 4.2 yet.in the dropdowns in the preview just put a version of Android that is less than 4.2

Answer (score 0):

Coping the above xml and paste it in to the device.xml file works for me , Thanks Nixiti,  it seems easy but it helps a lot

Answer (score 0):

Now It change as **devices.xml** (NOT device.xml) file inside USER_HOME/.android

Later versions of Android SDK tools have SDK_FOLDER/tools/lib/**devices.xml**

Answer (score 0):

Nothing serious. Just switch rendering version on your preview pane to lower version.

[image]