# Device configurations showing no default device. How to fix this?

Tags: intellij-idea

Brand new installation of IDEA 11 and Device Convigurations screen looks like this.

[image]

As I found from IDEA's docs, the default content is pulled from the XML file located at

`Default configurations are stored in Sdk_Directory/tools/lib/devices.xml`

I found this file and saw that it is full of content. However, Device configurations screen is still empty.

To repeat this is a brand new installation of IDEA 11 (the same with IDEA 12 preview) and brand new installation of Android SDK.

Why is this happening and how to fix this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How I solved this issue!

This quote of IntelliJ team helped me

> ```
> 1. Custom configurations are stored in Home_Directory/.android/devices.xml
> 2. Default configurations are stored in Sdk_Directory/tools/lib/devices.xml
> ```

1. installed brand new Android SDK
2. pulled devices.xml file from `Sdk_Directory/tools/lib/devices.xml`
3. copied it to `Home_Directory/.android/devices.xml`

Preview pane returned to previous state with **all devices**.

PS. this is a solution for Linux, but the same file exists in windows versions as well

Comment: i have replaced the file on windows but id doesn't help because the file is reset every time i re-open the project in IDE

Comment: i have the same problem, this solution does not work in windows

Comment: Guys, maybe you had a different problem than I did. But this worked in my case thou I am not sure if IDEA pulled content from default or personal XML file

Comment: Do you have access to Linux machine? Try pulling XML file from Linux SDK. I did reverse thing and it worked - pulled XML from windows machine and pasted it into Linux.

Answer (score 8):

Insert in the file %USER%\.android\devices.xml data from a previous version of SDK. For example, below:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<d:layout-devices
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/layout-devices/1">

    <d:device name="2.7in QVGA">
        <d:default>
            <d:screen-size>small</d:screen-size>
            <d:screen-ratio>notlong</d:screen-ratio>
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
            <d:pixel-density>ldpi</d:pixel-density>
            <d:touch-type>finger</d:touch-type>
            <d:keyboard-state>keyssoft</d:keyboard-state>
            <d:text-input-method>nokeys</d:text-input-method>
            <d:nav-state>navexposed</d:nav-state>
            <d:nav-method>nonav</d:nav-method>
            <d:screen-dimension>
                <d:size>240</d:size>
                <d:size>320</d:size>
            </d:screen-dimension>
            <d:xdpi>145</d:xdpi>
            <d:ydpi>145</d:ydpi>
        </d:default>

        <d:config name="Portrait">
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
        <d:config name="Landscape">
            <d:screen-orientation>land</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
    </d:device>

    <d:device name="2.7in QVGA slider">
        <d:default>
            <d:screen-size>small</d:screen-size>
            <d:screen-ratio>notlong</d:screen-ratio>
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
            <d:pixel-density>ldpi</d:pixel-density>
            <d:touch-type>finger</d:touch-type>
            <d:text-input-method>qwerty</d:text-input-method>
            <d:nav-state>navexposed</d:nav-state>
            <d:nav-method>nonav</d:nav-method>
            <d:screen-dimension>
                <d:size>240</d:size>
                <d:size>320</d:size>
            </d:screen-dimension>
            <d:xdpi>145</d:xdpi>
            <d:ydpi>145</d:ydpi>
        </d:default>

        <d:config name="Portrait">
            <d:keyboard-state>keyssoft</d:keyboard-state>
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
        <d:config name="Landscape, closed">
            <d:keyboard-state>keyssoft</d:keyboard-state>
            <d:screen-orientation>land</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
        <d:config name="Landscape, open">
            <d:keyboard-state>keysexposed</d:keyboard-state>
            <d:screen-orientation>land</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
    </d:device>

    <d:device name="3.2in HVGA slider (ADP1)">
        <d:default>
            <d:screen-size>normal</d:screen-size>
            <d:screen-ratio>notlong</d:screen-ratio>
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
            <d:pixel-density>mdpi</d:pixel-density>
            <d:touch-type>finger</d:touch-type>
            <d:text-input-method>qwerty</d:text-input-method>
            <d:nav-state>navexposed</d:nav-state>
            <d:nav-method>trackball</d:nav-method>
            <d:screen-dimension>
                <d:size>320</d:size>
                <d:size>480</d:size>
            </d:screen-dimension>
            <d:xdpi>180.6</d:xdpi>
            <d:ydpi>182</d:ydpi>
        </d:default>

        <d:config name="Portrait">
            <d:keyboard-state>keyssoft</d:keyboard-state>
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
        <d:config name="Landscape, closed">
            <d:keyboard-state>keyssoft</d:keyboard-state>
            <d:screen-orientation>land</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
        <d:config name="Landscape, open">
            <d:keyboard-state>keysexposed</d:keyboard-state>
            <d:screen-orientation>land</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
    </d:device>

    <d:device name="3.2in HVGA (ADP2)">
        <d:default>
            <d:screen-size>normal</d:screen-size>
            <d:screen-ratio>notlong</d:screen-ratio>
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
            <d:pixel-density>mdpi</d:pixel-density>
            <d:touch-type>finger</d:touch-type>
            <d:keyboard-state>keyssoft</d:keyboard-state>
            <d:text-input-method>nokeys</d:text-input-method>
            <d:nav-state>navexposed</d:nav-state>
            <d:nav-method>trackball</d:nav-method>
            <d:screen-dimension>
                <d:size>320</d:size>
                <d:size>480</d:size>
            </d:screen-dimension>
            <d:xdpi>180.6</d:xdpi>
            <d:ydpi>182</d:ydpi>
        </d:default>

        <d:config name="Portrait">
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
        <d:config name="Landscape">
            <d:screen-orientation>land</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
    </d:device>

    <d:device name="3.3in WQVGA">
        <d:default>
            <d:screen-size>normal</d:screen-size>
            <d:screen-ratio>long</d:screen-ratio>
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
            <d:pixel-density>ldpi</d:pixel-density>
            <d:touch-type>finger</d:touch-type>
            <d:keyboard-state>keyssoft</d:keyboard-state>
            <d:text-input-method>nokeys</d:text-input-method>
            <d:nav-state>navexposed</d:nav-state>
            <d:nav-method>nonav</d:nav-method>
            <d:screen-dimension>
                <d:size>240</d:size>
                <d:size>400</d:size>
            </d:screen-dimension>
            <d:xdpi>141</d:xdpi>
            <d:ydpi>141</d:ydpi>
        </d:default>

        <d:config name="Portrait">
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
        <d:config name="Landscape">
            <d:screen-orientation>land</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
    </d:device>
    <d:device name="3.4in FWQVGA">
        <d:default>
            <d:screen-size>normal</d:screen-size>
            <d:screen-ratio>long</d:screen-ratio>
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
            <d:pixel-density>ldpi</d:pixel-density>
            <d:touch-type>finger</d:touch-type>
            <d:keyboard-state>keyssoft</d:keyboard-state>
            <d:text-input-method>nokeys</d:text-input-method>
            <d:nav-state>navexposed</d:nav-state>
            <d:nav-method>nonav</d:nav-method>
            <d:screen-dimension>
                <d:size>240</d:size>
                <d:size>432</d:size>
            </d:screen-dimension>
            <d:xdpi>145</d:xdpi>
            <d:ydpi>145</d:ydpi>
        </d:default>

        <d:config name="Portrait">
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
        <d:config name="Landscape">
            <d:screen-orientation>land</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
    </d:device>

    <d:device name="3.7in WVGA (Nexus One)">
        <d:default>
            <d:screen-size>normal</d:screen-size>
            <d:screen-ratio>long</d:screen-ratio>
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
            <d:pixel-density>hdpi</d:pixel-density>
            <d:touch-type>finger</d:touch-type>
            <d:keyboard-state>keyssoft</d:keyboard-state>
            <d:text-input-method>nokeys</d:text-input-method>
            <d:nav-state>navexposed</d:nav-state>
            <d:nav-method>trackball</d:nav-method>
            <d:screen-dimension>
                <d:size>480</d:size>
                <d:size>800</d:size>
            </d:screen-dimension>
            <d:xdpi>254</d:xdpi>
            <d:ydpi>254</d:ydpi>
        </d:default>

        <d:config name="Portrait">
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
        <d:config name="Landscape">
            <d:screen-orientation>land</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
    </d:device>

    <d:device name="3.7in FWVGA slider">
        <d:default>
            <d:screen-size>normal</d:screen-size>
            <d:screen-ratio>long</d:screen-ratio>
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
            <d:pixel-density>hdpi</d:pixel-density>
            <d:touch-type>finger</d:touch-type>
            <d:text-input-method>qwerty</d:text-input-method>
            <d:nav-state>navhidden</d:nav-state>
            <d:nav-method>dpad</d:nav-method>
            <d:screen-dimension>
                <d:size>480</d:size>
                <d:size>854</d:size>
            </d:screen-dimension>
            <d:xdpi>265</d:xdpi>
            <d:ydpi>265</d:ydpi>
        </d:default>

        <d:config name="Portrait">
            <d:keyboard-state>keyssoft</d:keyboard-state>
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
        <d:config name="Landscape, closed">
            <d:keyboard-state>keyssoft</d:keyboard-state>
            <d:screen-orientation>land</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
        <d:config name="Landscape, open">
            <d:keyboard-state>keysexposed</d:keyboard-state>
            <d:screen-orientation>land</d:screen-orientation>
            <d:nav-state>navexposed</d:nav-state>
        </d:config>
    </d:device>

    <d:device name="4in WVGA (Nexus S)">
        <d:default>
            <d:screen-size>normal</d:screen-size>
            <d:screen-ratio>long</d:screen-ratio>
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
            <d:pixel-density>hdpi</d:pixel-density>
            <d:touch-type>finger</d:touch-type>
            <d:keyboard-state>keyssoft</d:keyboard-state>
            <d:text-input-method>nokeys</d:text-input-method>
            <d:nav-state>navexposed</d:nav-state>
            <d:nav-method>nonav</d:nav-method>
            <d:screen-dimension>
                <d:size>480</d:size>
                <d:size>800</d:size>
            </d:screen-dimension>
            <d:xdpi>235</d:xdpi>
            <d:ydpi>235</d:ydpi>
        </d:default>

        <d:config name="Portrait">
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
        <d:config name="Landscape">
            <d:screen-orientation>land</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
    </d:device>

    <d:device name="4.65in 720p (Galaxy Nexus)">
        <d:default>
            <d:screen-size>normal</d:screen-size>
            <d:screen-ratio>long</d:screen-ratio>
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
            <d:pixel-density>xhdpi</d:pixel-density>
            <d:touch-type>finger</d:touch-type>
            <d:keyboard-state>keyssoft</d:keyboard-state>
            <d:text-input-method>nokeys</d:text-input-method>
            <d:nav-state>navexposed</d:nav-state>
            <d:nav-method>nonav</d:nav-method>
            <d:screen-dimension>
                <d:size>720</d:size>
                <d:size>1280</d:size>
            </d:screen-dimension>
            <d:xdpi>316</d:xdpi>
            <d:ydpi>316</d:ydpi>
        </d:default>

        <d:config name="Portrait">
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
        <d:config name="Landscape">
            <d:screen-orientation>land</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
    </d:device>

    <d:device name="4.7in WXGA">
        <d:default>
            <d:screen-size>normal</d:screen-size>
            <d:screen-ratio>long</d:screen-ratio>
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
            <d:pixel-density>xhdpi</d:pixel-density>
            <d:touch-type>finger</d:touch-type>
            <d:keyboard-state>keyssoft</d:keyboard-state>
            <d:text-input-method>nokeys</d:text-input-method>
            <d:nav-state>navexposed</d:nav-state>
            <d:nav-method>nonav</d:nav-method>
            <d:screen-dimension>
                <d:size>1280</d:size>
                <d:size>720</d:size>
            </d:screen-dimension>
            <d:xdpi>320</d:xdpi>
            <d:ydpi>320</d:ydpi>
        </d:default>

        <d:config name="Portrait">
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
        <d:config name="Landscape">
            <d:screen-orientation>land</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
    </d:device>

    <d:device name="5.1in WVGA">
        <d:default>
            <d:screen-size>large</d:screen-size>
            <d:screen-ratio>long</d:screen-ratio>
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
            <d:pixel-density>mdpi</d:pixel-density>
            <d:touch-type>finger</d:touch-type>
            <d:keyboard-state>keyssoft</d:keyboard-state>
            <d:text-input-method>nokeys</d:text-input-method>
            <d:nav-state>navexposed</d:nav-state>
            <d:nav-method>nonav</d:nav-method>
            <d:screen-dimension>
                <d:size>480</d:size>
                <d:size>800</d:size>
            </d:screen-dimension>
            <d:xdpi>183</d:xdpi>
            <d:ydpi>183</d:ydpi>
        </d:default>

        <d:config name="Portrait">
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
        <d:config name="Landscape">
            <d:screen-orientation>land</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
    </d:device>

    <d:device name="5.4in FWVGA">
        <d:default>
            <d:screen-size>large</d:screen-size>
            <d:screen-ratio>long</d:screen-ratio>
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
            <d:pixel-density>mdpi</d:pixel-density>
            <d:touch-type>finger</d:touch-type>
            <d:keyboard-state>keyssoft</d:keyboard-state>
            <d:text-input-method>nokeys</d:text-input-method>
            <d:nav-state>navexposed</d:nav-state>
            <d:nav-method>nonav</d:nav-method>
            <d:screen-dimension>
                <d:size>480</d:size>
                <d:size>854</d:size>
            </d:screen-dimension>
            <d:xdpi>181</d:xdpi>
            <d:ydpi>181</d:ydpi>
        </d:default>

        <d:config name="Portrait">
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
        <d:config name="Landscape">
            <d:screen-orientation>land</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
    </d:device>

    <d:device name="7in WSVGA (Tablet)">
        <d:default>
            <d:screen-size>large</d:screen-size>
            <d:screen-ratio>long</d:screen-ratio>
            <d:screen-orientation>land</d:screen-orientation>
            <d:pixel-density>mdpi</d:pixel-density>
            <d:touch-type>finger</d:touch-type>
            <d:keyboard-state>keyssoft</d:keyboard-state>
            <d:text-input-method>nokeys</d:text-input-method>
            <d:nav-state>navexposed</d:nav-state>
            <d:nav-method>nonav</d:nav-method>
            <d:screen-dimension>
                <d:size>1024</d:size>
                <d:size>600</d:size>
            </d:screen-dimension>
            <d:xdpi>169</d:xdpi>
            <d:ydpi>169</d:ydpi>
        </d:default>

        <d:config name="Landscape">
            <d:screen-orientation>land</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
        <d:config name="Portrait">
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
    </d:device>

    <d:device name="7in WXGA (Nexus 7)">
        <d:default>
            <d:screen-size>large</d:screen-size>
            <d:screen-ratio>long</d:screen-ratio>
            <d:screen-orientation>land</d:screen-orientation>
            <d:pixel-density>tvdpi</d:pixel-density>
            <d:touch-type>finger</d:touch-type>
            <d:keyboard-state>keyssoft</d:keyboard-state>
            <d:text-input-method>nokeys</d:text-input-method>
            <d:nav-state>navexposed</d:nav-state>
            <d:nav-method>nonav</d:nav-method>
            <d:screen-dimension>
                <d:size>1280</d:size>
                <d:size>800</d:size>
            </d:screen-dimension>
            <d:xdpi>195</d:xdpi>
            <d:ydpi>200</d:ydpi>
        </d:default>

        <d:config name="Landscape">
            <d:screen-orientation>land</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
        <d:config name="Portrait">
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
    </d:device>

    <d:device name="10.1in WXGA (Tablet)">
        <d:default>
            <d:screen-size>xlarge</d:screen-size>
            <d:screen-ratio>long</d:screen-ratio>
            <d:screen-orientation>land</d:screen-orientation>
            <d:pixel-density>mdpi</d:pixel-density>
            <d:touch-type>finger</d:touch-type>
            <d:keyboard-state>keyssoft</d:keyboard-state>
            <d:text-input-method>nokeys</d:text-input-method>
            <d:nav-state>navexposed</d:nav-state>
            <d:nav-method>nonav</d:nav-method>
            <d:screen-dimension>
                <d:size>1280</d:size>
                <d:size>800</d:size>
            </d:screen-dimension>
            <d:xdpi>149</d:xdpi>
            <d:ydpi>149</d:ydpi>
        </d:default>

        <d:config name="Landscape">
            <d:screen-orientation>land</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
        <d:config name="Portrait">
            <d:screen-orientation>port</d:screen-orientation>
        </d:config>
    </d:device>
</d:layout-devices>
```

Comment: This solved this issue for me after updating to the latest SDK tools 21. In the version 21 Google has changed the devices.xml format, so I copied your version to the "home" directory and it works again. I am on Windows.

Comment: Copying this file worked for us (on Windows), except that we had to replace the file in the SDK/tools/lib/devices.xml directory. Putting it in the home directory didn't work for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

same in my case. this problem were appears when I update ADT. I guess problem is there...

Comment: I updated android sdk also but problem what I see is in devices.xml in .android and sdk_home/tools/lib ... devices.xml in .android using different schema as other stored in sdk_home ...

Comment: the problem with the new SDK is that they chenged the devices.xml format so the default devices are not loaded. I used the xml provided by Kris (and put it in the folder Kris told) and now I can see all the devices again :)