# IntelliJ Device Configurations List empty

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, osx-mountain-lion

I am having the same troubles as the folks in this Thread had: [Device configurations showing no default device. How to fix this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422872/device-configurations-showing-no-default-device-how-to-fix-this/13500307#13500307)

Unfortunately, the solution regarding the `.xml-File` did not work for me. After that I did a complete reinstall of `Java`, `Android SDK` and `IntelliJ`(after completely removing all setting etc)

I am running `OS X 10.8.2` and tried `InteliJ 11.1` and `12 EAP`.

I'm completely lost here and any Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: The issue will be fixed in the next IDEA 12 EAP (to be published at http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/IDEADEV/IDEA+12+EAP this week).

Comment: So, this is gonna be in the Verison after the 12.813? Thank you already.

Comment: Thanks, so that means waiting. ;D Sorry for my bad english.