# Eclipse Error when booting up - "Error when loading the SDK"

Tags: android, eclipse, macos, android-sdk-2.3

I'm trying get a simple android application running.

Every time I boot up eclipse, I get the following error:

> [2013-10-06 20:26:06 - Android SDK] Error when loading the SDK:
>
> Error: Error parsing /android-sdk-macosx/tools/lib/devices.xml
> cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'd:layout-devices'.

I've had no success in fixing this. Is this something I need to fix before moving on?

Comment: Check this out.

Hope this helps. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13422872/device-configurations-showing-no-default-device-how-to-fix-this/13429067#13429067

Comment: I tried...didnt work!